# Tinymce not working in angularjs mdDialog

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to use TinyMCE editor in angularjs mdDialog.
Worling Plukr: http://embed.plnkr.co/s3NsemdcDAtG7AoQRvLh/

Plunkr with issues: http://embed.plnkr.co/fL8kGLl3b4TNdxW1AtKG/

All features are working normally instead of drop down: 
http://prntscr.com/fop9u0
 It works fine if I increase the top position of drop down around 100px. http://prntscr.com/fope8o
I noticed that this problem appearing due to page scroll..

Can someone help me out to get these drop downs in right position.

Comment: It would be easier to answer with a Plunker reproducing the problem

Comment: To re-phrase what @KScandrett said. It's **impossible** to help you without  any code to work with.

Comment: Hi @KScandrett and "gforce301", I have edited my question by adding plunkr.

Comment: @om. as I see some style added at body tag. you can add one css hack `.md-dialog-is-showing {
          position: relative !important;
          top: auto !important;
      }` , By adding this you need to scroll up, once popup open.

Comment: @om why style for body is being added top seems to be a minus value. is tiny mce is adding this or you are doing it? Possible fix is to add same body top(Positive value)to the pop up top. But its not clean

Comment: @gusaindpk  I didn't add anything myself, as you can see in Plunkr.. there is no custom CSS or JS, It's only tinymce and material design.

Comment: @om. Plunker links are not working

Comment: @ Prateek, you should Refresh the plunkr, http://prntscr.com/ft4ufh

Answer (score 3):

There is a top position calculation issue, It can be fixed adding below code in app.js file in 
`

```
$scope.addMoreInfoFunction = function(event) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.mce-btn').on('click', function() {
                var bodyTop = $('body').offset().top;
                if (bodyTop < 0) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var top = parseInt($('#mceu_50').css('top'));
                        var newTop = top / 2 - bodyTop - 30;
                        $('#mceu_50').css('top', newTop);
                        console.log(newTop);
                    }, 300);
                }
            });
        }, 300);
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: ['$scope', '$mdDialog', DialogAddMoreInfoController],
            templateUrl: 'addMoreInfo.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: event,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        });
        };
        });
```

`

**Calculation can be corrected, let know if it helps**

Comment: @om did you try the solution?

Answer (score 1):

A CSS conflict possible a forced margin on all divs. So this is more of a integration issue than a tinymce bug. We have a few reset rules to remove the common conflicts.

```css
   <style>
   .mce-tooltip
  {
    position: fixed !important;
  }
  .mce-panel.mce-floatpanel.mce-menu 
  {
    position: fixed !important;
  }
    </style>
```

**Its not working perfectly. But it might help you to do something.**