# Angularjs: Tinymce is not working inside md-dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, material-design, angularjs-material

I am working on a project with angularJs. It is working fine. I am using Angularjs Material and tinymce. Both also works fine.

But whenever I try to create tinymce inside a material dialog md-dialog. The tinymce is not editable. It is just freezing.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779101/tinymce-not-working-in-angularjs-mddialog). But did not help.

I regenerated the problem on plunkr. Here is the code on plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/33tasB4zwQOH787PvSWD?p=preview

My dialog is pre-rendered. and here is my real code:

view.html

```
<md-button type="button" ng-click="vm.showAddDialog($event)" class="md-raised md-primary">
  <md-icon>add</md-icon> Ekle
</md-button>
<div style="visibility: hidden">
  <div class="md-dialog-container" id="addQuestion">
    <md-dialog layout-padding>
      <h4>Soru Ekle {{vm.newQuestion}}</h4>
      <div ng-if="vm.isLoading" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-progress-circular md-diameter="90"></md-progress-circular>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="!vm.isLoading">

        <div layout="column" style="width:750px">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin:0">
            <label>Soru</label>
            <textarea ng-model="vm.newQuestion.question" style="height: 75px !important;overflow-y: scroll;" class="md-line-10"></textarea>
          </md-input-container>
          <textarea ui-tinymce="vm.tinymceOptions" ng-model="vm.newQuestion.answer" aria-label="Answer" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #f1f1f1; outline: none;"
                class="md-line-10"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="end start">
          <md-button ng-click="vm.hideAddDialog()" md-noink class="md-primary">Kapat</md-button>
          <md-button ng-click="vm.saveCategory()" class="md-raised md-primary">Kaydet</md-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-dialog>
  </div>
</div>
```

inside controller.js

```
...
vm.tinymceOptions = {
  plugins: 'link image media code textcolor colorpicker lists advlist',
  toolbar: 'formatselect | undo redo | forecolor backcolor | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | numlist bullist outdent indent | code | fontselect | fontsizeselect',
  image_advtab: true,
  language_url: ic.CDN + '/assets/tiny-langs/langs/tr.js',
  onBlur: function () { }
};
...
vm.showAddDialog = function(ev) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    contentElement: '#addQuestion',
    parent: angular.element($window.document.querySelector('body')),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: false
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a template and controller instead of contentElement.
To fix the plunker, replace index.html with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS material-sidenav Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.10/angular-material.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.7.13/tinymce.min.js" integrity="sha256-t4dpNoDZ4N2yIKa2i9CJhjzQKEwpO7C33fZ1XdN+gTU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.13" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.5"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/angular-aria.js" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.5"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/angular-animate.js" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.5"></script>
  <script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.10/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tinymce/0.0.19/tinymce.js" integrity="sha256-yMo8Z3ceGwgCGY4pKRqnKsSevgfZXftzHIy/TflrgyQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  This one works
  <form method="post">
    <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>
  </form>
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showPrerenderedDialog($event)">
    Click Me! This one is not working
  </md-button>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myDialog.html" >
    <md-dialog layout-padding>
        We are unable to edit tinymce inside md-dialog!!
        <form method="post">
          <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>
        </form>
      </md-dialog>

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Then, replace the app.js with this code

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.tinymce'])
  .controller('AppCtrl',
    function($scope, $mdDialog) {
      $scope.showPrerenderedDialog = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
          //using controller and templateUrl
          controller: ['$scope', '$mdDialog', TinyController],
          templateUrl: 'myDialog.html',
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          targetEvent: ev,
          clickOutsideToClose: true
        });
      };
      $scope.tinymceModel = '';

      $scope.tinymceOptions = {
        plugins: 'link image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
      };
    })

    //controller for our TinyMCE
    function TinyController($scope, $mdDialog) {
      $scope.tinymceOptions = {
        plugins: 'link image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
      };
    }
```

For more information I would recommend checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779101/tinymce-not-working-in-angularjs-mddialog) Stack Overflow question.

I also made a plunker with the fixed code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/P2imyy9Z4f7psOmvc6K5?p=info), I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok i see that it is working thanks. But what is the issue with contentElement? Isn't that a kind of bug in angularjs material? I will be waiting for some answer solving with contentElement. if no answer still, I will accept this answer and I may report to angularjs material project as a bug

Comment: A blind guess but there might be some AngularJS HTML template compilation involved that simply doesn't occur when you use the contentElement option. This way AngularJS fetches and compiles the HTML template with proper scoping etc.

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed, contentElement does not work because you are trying to use it as a template, and contentElement only accepts DOM elements that are already created. I feel [this](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10690) github issue does a really good job of explaining it and for more detail on contentElement I would check out the [$mdDialog Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog). I am really sorry that my solution doesn't use contentElement but I hope that this helps explain why you are getting this error. Have a wonderful day!